# Error 8007007A - The data area passed to a system call is too small. When Adding Components to COM+ Catalog

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, com+

We are in the process of migrating COM+ applications\components written in VB6 to .Net.  We have successfully migrated most of our components(~50) which consists of 1000+ classes. One of the last (and largest) components has 356 classes and when adding the VB6 version to the COM+ Catalog via Components Services, it loads fine.  After conversion to .Net, when attempting to add to the catalog, we get the 8007007A error.  If we remove some of the classes (specifically reduced down to 347), the component loads like a charm. This behavior is displayed on both Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012. The actual dll being added is smaller in .Net than in VB6 (no surprise), ~5k vs. ~1k.  Any ideas as to what the issue really is? (Don't really trust the error message). Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How, exactly, are you adding the components? The particular error you're seeing is one of those ugly yet pervasive errors that can hit just about any Windows box going back to XP, but seems most commonly to occur during a "Windows Update" session. The code is literally an "ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER" code, which at least prompted me to ask exactly how you're adding the components. Might shed some additional light.

Comment: Right now, they are being added via the Component Services UI:1. Run comexp.msc
2. Expand Component Services
3. Expand Computers
4. Expand My Computer
5. Expand COM+ Applications
6. Expand the COM+ Application to add the component
7. Right-Click Components, select New, Component to launch the Component Install Wizard
8. Click Next
9. Click Install New Component
10. Select dll
11. Click Next
12. Click Finish

Comment: I won't swear to this, but I think additions like this are actually spanwed off of the COM+ "System Application" and I think that might be the one giving you the fault by virtue of adding so many classes at once. If the sys app is spawning off what amounts to hidden console sessions it could be something as simple as the arguments being passed to the spawed session just being too long - and that tends to be backed up by your having taken out a few classes and it working. Short of repackaging the components into separately loaded DLL's, you may not have a great many options :(

Comment: One other thing - you *might* look into writing an app that leverages the COM Admin interfaces/objects and see if adding your classes programmatically that way might be of benefit and eliminate the problem that way.

Comment: Well, the only thing is that the VB6 version of the component with the same number of classes loads fine.  As to adding them programmatically, that is actually what we normally do for a development environement and when our application is deployed at a customer site. I will take another look at that though.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details on how exactly you created the substitutes in .NET.  You can certainly get this to blow up badly, a Q&D way is to expose the classes instead of the interfaces, that brings in a big chunk of the .NET framework through mscorlib.tlb.